# User DB - valid and invalid requests

Tags: php, mysql, database

So this is what I got:

`users` table

- username (text)
- status (a number)

`requests` table

- username (text, the same as in users table)
- eligible (0 or 1)
- valid (0 or 1)

I want to `SELECT` all users whose number of eligible (eligible = 1) AND valid (valid = 1) requests is larger than number of all eligible (eligible = 1) AND invalid (valid = 0) requests AND the number of all eligible requests made by the user is higher than 10.

What SQL query is the best and fastest to achieve that?

---

This is where I am at now - it shows me the valid and all requests, but it should definitely not be like that - too many SELECTS and it's extremely slow query...

```
SELECT U.username, 
(SELECT COUNT(R.username) FROM requests AS R
  WHERE U.username = R.username AND eligible = 1 AND valid = 1) AS ValidRequests,
(SELECT COUNT(R.username) FROM requests AS R
 WHERE U.username = R.username AND eligible = 1) AS AllRequests
FROM users AS U;
```

Comment: Give us some code that you already have tried

Comment: @SuperDj Some code added to the first post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express the logic using `group by` and a `having` clause.  In this case, you can mimic boolean logic by doing arithmetic manipulations.  So, `eligible*valid` is `1` only when the request is both eligible and valid.

The rest is just a translation of your conditions into the appropriate logic:

```
select username
from requests
group by username
having sum(eligible) > 10 and
       sum(eligible*valid) > sum(eligible*(1-valid));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question...

First qualifier:  requests is larger than number of all eligible (eligible = 1) AND invalid (valid = 0) requests

```
select count(username) from requests where eligible = 1 and valid = 0;
```

If the number here is higher than 10, then "AND the number of all eligible requests made by the user is higher than 10" will also have to be met. Otherwise, we should set it to ten.

So, I think the following meets your criteria:

```
select username from requests where eligible = 1 and valid = 1 group by username having count(username) > ?
```

Binding the greater of the two values of the first query or 10.